# MongoDB not updating data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to log module in database like if the module is turned on or off
and I'm running few checks but it seems like it's messing with it

```js
                return MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},function(err, db) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    var dbo = db.db("sdb");
                    dbo.collection("servers").findOne({id: `${message.guild.id}`}, function(err, result) {
                        if(result.verification == "true") return message.channel.send("", {embed: new Discord.RichEmbed().setAuthor("Verification System:").setDescription("Verifications are already Enabled!").setColor("RED")})
                        if(!message.guild.channels.find(c => c.id === result.verificationchannel)) return message.channel.send("", {embed:new Discord.RichEmbed().setAuthor("Verification System:").setDescription("Verification Channels Must be setup!"+ `\nUse: \`${result.prefix}verification setchannel\``)})
                        if(!message.guild.roles.find(r => r.id === result.onjoinrole)) return message.channel.send("",{embed:new Discord.RichEmbed().setDescription("`Autorole` must be Setup in order to Enable this module!").setAuthor("Verification System:").setColor("RED")})
                        dbo.collection("servers").updateOne({ id: message.guild.id }, {$set: {verification: `true`}}, function(err, res) {
                        message.channel.send("", {
                            embed: new Discord.RichEmbed()
                            .setAuthor("Verification System:")
                            .setDescription(`Successfully Enabled Verifications!\nChannel: <#${result.verificationchannel}>`)
                            .setFooter(`Enabled by: ${message.author.username}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                           })
                        })
                  })
                  if (err) throw err;
                  db.close();
                })
```

the database isn't updating (No errors)

Comment: Why do you set 'true' as a sting?

Comment: I tried to set it to true but it didn't work. So I tried it as a string.

Comment: First you must be sure that you find the doc you want to update. Just make `console.log` of that doc.